# How Does JavaScript code beautifier access content in <pre> before parsing?

Tags: javascript, html

It seems like with JS API such as prettify or code beautifier from Google, it's possible to have code directly written like this in the HTML page:

```
<pre class="prettify">
    // this is an example
    #include <iostream>
    int main() {
        std::cerr << "test\n";
    }
</pre>
```

What's unusual is that it seems possible to use special characters such as `<` or `>` directly in the content of the `<pre>` tag, without it being interpreted as a tag by the browser's parser? How is it possible? My understanding is that the first thing that happens when a page is created, is that when the HTML code is made available to the browser, it will parse it, generating a "valid" DOM document on the fly. Thus in the current example it should create something like this:

```
<pre class="...">
    <iostream>
    ...
    </iostream>
</pre>
```

However, the document of code beautifier program such as [pretiffy](https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html) or [the code beautifier project by Google](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/), seems to suggest their JS scripts can actually parse the content of the  tag (or `code`), and modify it on the fly, which means that somehow something like `<iostream>` would have not been processed by the parser first and converted to a tag (and is being left untouched as being part of the content/innerHTML of the  tag). To my knowledge there's no possible way in JS to actually get the content of a document and change it before the page is loaded (especially as a DOM document would have not been formed yet)? This is a mystery to me.

I have no idea how this is possible? Does someone have a clue and could explain?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible. Those tools read the DOM of the element after it has been processed by the HTML parser.

You can [see a live example](http://test-cases.dorward.me.uk/stackoverflow/25592758/) of it not working.

You still need to express your source code in correct HTML for it to display properly.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you. I have seen an example in which the code was just copy/pasted from the code editor and the `<`/`>` were not changed, but maybe it was just misleading and an example someone had not tested. Thank you (sadly I can't put my hands on this example any longer).